# Why a div width specified in pixels is becoming smaller?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, precision

I have three `div` occupying the whole width of the container. The left and right `div` (should) have a fixed width, like `300px`. The main `div` should occupy the remaining space. However, if the text in the main `div` increases, it grows in a way that the other two `div` become smaller than 300 pixels.

CSS

```
.container {
    display:flex;
}
.main {
  background:#CCC;
    width:auto;
}
.left {
  background:#8F8;
    width:300px;
}
.right {
    background:#F80;
    width:300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>
  Left
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
  Main with long enough text to occupy more than a line, and a few more just to be sure.
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
  Right
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLLnbo0u/

One can see the problem if the right `div` or the main text is removed: the left `div` automatically increases (back to 300 pixels). How can I get the left and right `div` to be precisely 300 pixels, and the main `div` to occupy the remaining space, regardless of text length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `flex-shrink` property specifies the flex shrink factor of a flex item and determines how much the flex item will shrink relative to the rest of the flex items in the flex container when there isn't enough space.

Its default is `1`, and as you omitted it, it means all items will shrink equally.

So if you add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the `left`/`right`, they will keep their width, as the value `0` means they are not allowed to shrink at all.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLLnbo0u/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
 display:flex;
}
.main {
  background:#CCC;
 width:auto;
}
.left {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background:#8F8;
 width:300px;
}
.right {
  flex-shrink: 0;
 background:#F80;
 width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>
  Left
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
  Main with long enough text to occupy more than a line, and a few more just to be sure.
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
  Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) doesn't explain how other values work, though.